# Improving dynamic range of an ADC by stitching waveforms together

Tags: adc

I am trying to improve the dynamic range of an ADC, by using a second ADC which is the original signal attenuated by a known amount (\$x\$ dB).

So the two signals could be approximated (ignoring any phase differences):
\$y_1(t) = A\sin(\omega t)\$
\$y_2(t) = y_1(t)\$ attenuated by \$x\$ dB

I originally thought about solving this problem by using a 'stacked ADC' approach, which would be to have both signals be analysed and to choose the output of the adc which has not saturated.

However given that the frequency and attenuation of the waves would be a known quantity, would it be possible to combine or 'stitch' these waveforms together into one waveform mathematically by post-processing, and improve the dynamic range that way?

The problem was put to me by my professor but I'm at a loss as to how I would go about it.

Comment: Just to be clear, 10 dB is not the same as 10X so please clarify. Also having increased DR is a little ambiguous it is simply the ratio of max to min, so you can increase max, decrease min or both.  IS there some other criteria?

Comment: In this case it will be, since 10dB drop the second signal will mean the second signal will be 0.1 of the first signal. If there was a 20dB drop then the amplitude of the second signal will be 0.01 that of the first (http://sss-mag.com/db.html).

No other criteria, though I'm not sure what you mean by this second part. I'm just attempting to use 2 adc's to increase the DR of one signal by stitching together two waveforms. Each ADC will have a different max and min and I would like to combine these, if it is feasible.

Comment: You just contradicted what you wrote in your OP, see y2 above.

Comment: I really don't see how. If I attenuate y1 by 20dB, then y2 will equal 0.01*y1 (or 100 times drop in the power). What I wrote in the OP was 10dB drop where y2 will equal 0.1*y1 (or 10 times drop in the power). Is that wrong?

Comment: When we speak of attenuating something by x dB, we are customarily referring to a ratio of power, rather than of amplitude.  The former would be the square of the later.

Comment: In terms of the idea overall, it's not immediately clear how it would work.  If the smaller signal ADC is not saturated, what use is the larger one?  But if it is saturated, then what use is it?  If you only use one at a time, you are no longer talking about instantaneous dynamic range, but rather AGC-compensated dynamic range, and instead of doing AGC by variable gain/attenuation, you are simply doing it by picking which ADC to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see I shouldn't be mixing up power and amplitudes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I edited the main post which hopefully clarifies misunderstandings on my part. In terms of the idea, if the smaller signal is not saturated but uses a large portion of the ADC range, then the low power accuracy will be increased. If the large signal is also not saturated and uses a large portion of the ADC range, then it will give greater accuracy of higher power values. Since the difference in power levels is known I want to see if I can use both at once. Though if either are saturated then that ADC will be unusable. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Rushing. Not fully thought through. "Precision" of upper ADC may have to be to 1/N th of a LSB if it is to be directly combined with lower ADC. eg if division ratio is 8:1 the upper ADC will need 3 bits of accuracy within its LSD or it will switch beteen bits asynchronousl;y with lower ADC. I say "precision" as there are issues of accuracy, resolution, linearity, ... . I'm not sure you gain anything and may lose something if both ADCs are never saturated.

Comment: There's also a question about how little noise you can get on the *original input signal* - no point measuring down to 1 fkteenth of a gnat's hair if the noise is accounting for the lower N bits of your measurement. Search Linear Technology's website for appnotes by Bob Pease & Jim Williams, they wrote some magnificent stuff about low-noise measurement etc. (generally, anything they wrote is worth a read)

Comment: @user19475 - it doesn't work.  If the data from one ADC is relevant, that from another with substantially different range will be either irrelevant (in the sense of unable to contribute improvement) or entirely unusable - what you have is simply a two-gain switchable AGC.  You might want to look at schemes which actually do work - flash ADCs where you simply build more comparators to get a single-cycle result, or techniques where your result improves over many cycles such as successive approximation and sigma-delta.